# Laravel - Sync pivot table according to array

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, pivot

I am making a VueJS form where the user can edit a step. A step can have many parent products. The logic is that a step can belong to multiple products. I have a table called products, product_step(pivot table) and steps.

The array when the user first loads the page is filled with the parent products this stap has.

[image]

This array is changed according to what the user decided to do on the frontend. Let say they would like that product *n* no longer has access to this step. In that case, the product gets removed from the array.

The problem I'm facing is, that I don't know how to sync the Pivot table to this behaviour.

**Scenario**

Let's say the user loads the page and the parent products that this step has are `[101,102]`. The ID of the step is 2. The Pivot table would like the following

[image]

So let's say the user decided to remove product `101` and add product `104` and `106`. The array would then look like this `[101, 104, 106]` But the pivot table needs to sync this behaviour aswell. How can I accomplish that?

I tried something like this but this way it can only detach it, not add when necessary

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    foreach($request->data['parentProducts'] as $configurableProduct) {
      $product = Product::find($configurableProduct['id']);
      $product->steps()->detach($id);
    }
}
```

**PRODUCT MODEL**

```
 /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function steps()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Step::class, 'product_step', 'product_id', 'step_id')->orderBy('order');
    }
```

Comment: Check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations. You can call `$product->steps()->sync($ids)`, or `$step->products()->sync($ids)`. Sync will attach the ids found in `$ids`, and detach any that aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't flipping your logic around solve your problem. This would detach and add the products on a given step, which i guess is what the user is actually editing?

```
$step = Step::find($id);
$step->products()->sync(collect($request->data['parentProducts'])->pluck('id'));
```

Bonus points, you can also use model binding, for your Step and make the code even more clean. Requires that the route parameter is called step.

```
public function update(Request $request, Step $step)
    $step->products()->sync(collect($request->data['parentProducts'])->pluck('id'));
}
```